# Apache RewriteRule to subdirectory

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need to redirect myhomepage.com/ to myhomepage.com/sub/

When I read the guide at apache.org/docs/1.3/misc/rewriteguide.html I have no clue what they are talking about. Hence I decided to friendly ask one of the experts here. I guess it takes just some seconds to figure that rule out.

Thanks, Carin.

Answer (score 5):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule !^sub/ sub%{REQUEST_URI}
```

It will redirect any requested URL path that does not start with `/sub/` (`!^sub/`) internally to `/sub/` (`sub%{REQUEST_URI}`).

This rule is for the .htaccess configuration file in your document root. If you want to use it in your httpd.conf, prepend the pattern with a `/`.

And if you want an external redirect, prepend the substition with a `/` too and add the `[R]` flag:

```
RewriteRule !^sub/ sub%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to redirect `http://myhomepage.com/` (i.e. you don't need to redirect `http://myhomepage.com/example.html` to `http://myhomepage.com/sub/example.html`), the rule is as simple as:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://myhomepage.com/sub/ [R=301,L]
```